# How to use popen3 library in Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, cmd

I tried all the code (mostly popen or open gem) in SO posts and blogs like these - 
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html

Nothing works because of the error -

```
C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:57:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:57:in `popen3'
```

Sample code -

```
require 'open3'
cmd = 'git push heroku master'
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  puts "stdout is:" + stdout.read
  puts "stderr is:" + stderr.read
end
```

How do I make this work with this old ruby 1.8 gem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `open3` gem just doesn't work on Windows. =/

[`IO::popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-popen) is the closest thing I can think of.

Comment: `IO::popen` doesn't capture the `STDERR`, so there's no way to do it the same way. Now, if you're trying to do something particular then you should probably ask it in another question since the answer to this question is "You can't use `open3` in Windows."